# XPath to compare two distinct attributes of two elements

Tags: xml, xpath

Suppose I have this XML:

```
<x>
<e s="1" t="A"/>
<e s="2" t="A"/>
<e s="1" t="B"/>
</x>
```

Is there any way to write an xpath to find whether there are two distinct nodes named "e" which have the same value for @s but different values of @t. The first part is easy:

```
//e[@s = //e/@s]
```

as is the second part:

```
//e[@t != //e[@t]]
```

But I don't see any way to construct an xpath that compares two different attributes for two separate elements "e". Is there a way within the xpath syntax, or is it hopeless?

Comment: Excellent question: +1. See my answer for the solution. :)

Comment: I dont understand what "but a different value of @t for *the same node*" is supposed to mean? Please, clarify the question!

Comment: OK. I think I understand the question now. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The requested nodes cannot be selected by a single XPath 1.0 expression**.

If the hosting language is XSLT 1.0, then an expression using the `current()` function can be constructed, that selects the desired nodes.

**Use the following XPath 2.0 expression:**

```
for $x
           in
             /*/e[@s
                 = (preceding-sibling::e
                   |
                    following-sibling::e
                    )
                     /@s
                ],

           $y in /*/e[@s = $x/@s]

         return
            $x[not(@t = $y/@t)]
```

Comment: Probably I should clarify a bit. The XPath above will match the third element in this XML:
    <x>
 <e s="2" t="B"/>
 <e s="1" t="A"/>
 <e s="1" t="A"/>
   </x>

When it shouldn't. It matches e[2]/@s with e[1]/@s, and matches e[2]/@t with e[0]/@t; But neither e[0] nor e[1] match both conditions. I'm really wondering if there is a way to only select on e[x] if e[y] fulfills both of the matching criteria.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for an XPath 1.0 answer...but at least I know it can't be done and can stop butting my head against the problem!